# How to create custom messages for alerting monitors in OpenSearch, Kibana?

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, opensearch

I am struggling on creating a customized message for my OpenSearch alerting system. I am creating an alerting system that would trigger the alert for a particular event(e.g CPU utilization if a particular service reaches a specific threshold). I would like for this customized message to include any fields/metrics that I am tracking, or even if I would like to attach a dashboard link to message, or any name. Currently OpenSearch is only allowing me to include messages related to the alerting page. I attached picture for clairty
While browsing the web I noticed that I can implement some JSON mechanisms referencing the Mustache template. Any suggestions or walk through or how it can be done. My overall goal is to include a link & custom message in the alerting message that will be sent out to required destination.

[The type of messages thats included in OpenSearch alerting page.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9UNDh.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

@Viewsp although this not related to Elasticsearch (wrong tag included), but you can refer to the fields in payload or aggregation resultset of the alert using similar approach as shown in your snapshot, its just the path of field which will be different.

So, if you have a field called cpu in your log, it can be accessed as: {{ctx.payload.hits.hits[0].cpu}} from payload depending on the _source log field hierarchy. Basically hits[0] refers to the first result in your search payload which is followed by telemetry path of your field to be included.

I would suggest creating a watcher for your usecase to have more knowledge on how fields can be accessed and how does the ctx.payload look like (including aggregations):

Watcher from Kibana :https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/watcher-ui.html

Watcher from DevTools: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/xpack-alerting.html

Comment: You can use mustache templating to iterate through the hits similar to:
`{{#context.hits}} CPU: {{_source.cpu}} ContainerID: {{_source.container_id}} {{/context.hits}}`.
Essentially you need to open the context array, get the property values followed by closing the array.. the iteration of multiple results is performed implicitly so need to worry about that.